# Why my Android and objective-c code get different hmac-sha1 result?

Tags: android, objective-c, base64, sha1, hmac

I am writing a function that take a key and url and generate a signature. I am using hmac-sha1. But I got different signatures between Android code and objective-c code:

Objective-C:

```
- (NSString *)hmacsha1:(NSString *)url secretKey:(NSString *)secretKey
{
    const char *cKey  = [secretKey cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    const char *cData = [url cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);

    NSData *HMAC = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC
                                          length:sizeof(cHMAC)];

    NSString *hash = [HMAC base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];


    return hash;
}
```

Android:

```
public static String hmacsha1(String url, String secretKey) throws
        UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        InvalidKeyException
{
    secretKey = secretKey.replace('-', '+');
    secretKey = secretKey.replace('_', '/');

    byte[] key = Base64.decode(secretKey, Base64.DEFAULT);

    SecretKeySpec sha1Key = new SecretKeySpec(key, "HmacSHA1");

    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
    mac.init(sha1Key);

    byte[] sigBytes = mac.doFinal(url.getBytes());

    String signature = Base64.encodeToString(sigBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

    // convert the signature to 'web safe' base 64
    signature = signature.replace('+', '-');
    signature = signature.replace('/', '_');

    return signature;
}
```

Comment: I am also getting different values in ios and android. any update on this. Bit urgent. is your problem solved

Comment: @poyo fever did you found a solution for above

Answer (score 1):

The method that worked for me to generate **hmac-sha1** string exactly same as the android string

```
- (NSData *)hmacForKeyAndData:(NSString *)key data:(NSString *)url
    {
        const char *cKey  = [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        const char *cData = [url cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
        CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);
        return [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];
    }
```